# Counting occurrences in Vim without marking the buffer changed

Tags: vim

In order to know how many times a pattern exists in current buffer, I do:

```
:%s/pattern-here/pattern-here/g
```

It gives the number of occurrences of the pattern, but is obviously cumbersome and also has the side-effect of setting the 'changed' status.

Is there a more elegant way to count?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

To avoid the substitution, leave the second pattern empty, and add the “n” flag:

```
:%s/pattern-here//gn
```

This is described as [an official tip](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tips.html#count-items).

Comment: even more cumbersome, but at least it is now official that there is no elegant way...

Comment: If you've already performed a search using /, it becomes just :%s///gn

Comment: So just add it to your .vimrc

Comment: I found quite useful following mapping: `nnoremap <leader>n :%s///gn <CR>` to count occurrences of the last search

Comment: There's no way to make this count go into a variable right? That's what I need...

Comment: Actually I think there is a way to programmatically obtain the number of matches using this by using `:redir`

Answer (score 9):

```
:help count-items
```

In VIM 6.3, here's how you do it.

```
:set report=0
:%s/your_word/&/g    # returns the count without substitution
```

In VIM 7.2, here's how you'd do it:

```
:%s/your_word/&/gn   # returns the count, n flag avoids substitution
```

Comment: I had a big file and following this approach was much quicker than grep.

Answer (score 5):

```
:!cat %| grep -c "pattern"
```

It's not exactly vim command, but it will give you what you need from vim.
You can map it to the command if you need to use it frequently.

Comment: More simply `:!grep -c "pattern" %`

Comment: This `grep` solution is showing me the number of lines containing "pattern", not the actual quantity of "pattern" instances.  (There are more than one per line sometimes.)  This seems to work though: `:!grep -o "pattern" % | wc -l` (with the -o flag, grep prints only the matching parts of a matching line, with each match on a separate line; pipe to wc -l for a count of those lines.)

Answer (score 2):

The vimscript [IndexedSearch](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1682) enhances the Vim search commands to display "At match #N out of M matches".

Answer (score 1):

Put the cursor on the word you want to count and execute the following.

```
:%s/<c-r><c-w>//gn
```

See `:h c_ctrl-r_ctrl-w`

Answer (score -1):

vimgrep is your friend here:

```
vimgrep pattern %
```

Shows:

```
(1 of 37)
```

Comment: This does not count occurences, but counts lines containing the pattern. So if pattern occers twice in a line, it would only be counted once.